# Telerik reporting - unable to get report parameters

Tags: .net-core, report, telerik-reporting

I have a .net core app in which I have a Telerik report which has two parameters

[image]

and I have the code like so

```
$("#summaryReport").click(function () {
                var viewer = $("#reportViewer1").data("telerik_ReportViewer");
                viewer.reportSource({
                    report: "Sumaren.trdp",
                    parameters: {}
                });
                viewer.refreshReport();
            });


            $("#reportViewer1")
                .telerik_ReportViewer({

                    serviceUrl: "api/reports/",

                    //ReportSource - report description
                    reportSource: {
                        // The report can be set to a report file name (trdx report definition)
                        // or CLR type name (report class definition).
                    },

                    viewMode: telerikReportViewer.ViewModes.INTERACTIVE,

                    scaleMode: telerikReportViewer.ScaleModes.SPECIFIC,

                    scale: 1.0,
                    enableAccessibility: true,

                    ready: function () {
                        this.refreshReport();
                    },
                });
```

I keep getting the error `Unable to get report parameters. Report 'ReportName' cannot be resolved.`
Do I have to do something with the parameters in the `reportSource`? I think that when you add parameters via the Telerik Report Designer, do don't add anything in the `reportSource` besides the report name.The Telerik Designer previews the report just fine, works like it's supposed to but when I run the app it just keeps saying this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late for the party, but will try to answer - maybe it would be useful for someone else.
Since you're not using an absolute path to the report when setting the **viewer.reportSource**, the engine will search for it in the folder specified in the [ReportServiceConfiguration](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/telerik-reporting-rest-service-aspnetcore-mvc-core3). That configuration should be registered somewhere in your Startup.cs class, where the dependencies for ReportsController are added. It should look something like this:

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IReportServiceConfiguration>(sp =>
new ReportServiceConfiguration
{
    ReportingEngineConfiguration = ConfigurationHelper.ResolveConfiguration(sp.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>()),
    HostAppId = "ReportingCore3App",
    Storage = new FileStorage(),
    ReportSourceResolver = new UriReportSourceResolver(
        System.IO.Path.Combine(sp.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>().ContentRootPath, "Reports"))
});
```

The value assigned to ReportSourceResolver says how the reports will be resolved. In this case it will look for the reports in the **\root\Reports** folder, where **root** is the root folder of your .NET Core application.